# surface blinks when surfaceview inside coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, surfaceview, touch-event, android-coordinatorlayout

My custom surfaceview does not draw properly when touching, it's inside a coordinatorlayout.
how can I fix it?

I have an Fragment which contains a surfaceView like this:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- this is an SurfaceView! -->
            <com.my.app.CustomView
                android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And, It will be replace into an CoordinatorView,
layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/mainView">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/WexTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="@style/IconTitleTabLayout">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

when fragment attached it looks working, and the custom surfaceview show at proper position, but .

the problem is : when I touch on the custom surfaceview, invoke redraw the view,the surface draws some frame (about 1/3 -1/2 frames ) offsets to the top (the offset distance is about the total height of toolbar), so the view blinks all the time on touching.

> I tried to remove 
>           `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` of the container FrameLayout (id=content), the surface view not blink anymore, but without coordinatorlayout behavior, it's not at the proper position

thanks for any solution or discuss of the machanism

Comment: Hi, thanks for mentioning you removed the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. It worked for me with SurfaceView for camera preview. I added a top margin of height `?attr/actionBarSize` to the SurfaceView's container (my content view). Now the positioning is good and the blinking is gone. My content view can't be scrolled, so I don't know what happens if it's scrollable.